# Trying to make a list array with txt data, Python

Tags: python, arrays, txt

```
   44.5000   70.5000    1.0000
   44.0000   66.0000    1.0000
   33.0000   76.5000    1.0000
```

I am trying to make this kind of data into an array like this using numpy

```
([[44.5000, 70.5000, 1.0000], [44.0000,66.0000,1.0000],[3.0000,76.5000,1.0000]])
```

I tried this code but this code requires me to input a data hundred times

```
t_d = [list(map(float, input().split())) for _ in range(60)]
```

so is there any way to make the data in txt file directly to array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = np.loadtxt(r'c:\test\nptext.txt')
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[44.5 70.5  1. ]
 [44.  66.   1. ]
 [33.  76.5  1. ]]
```

### Edit2 (in-memory file)

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

txt = """44.5000 70.5000 1.0000 
44.0000 66.0000 1.0000 
33.0000 76.5000 1.0000
"""
mfile = StringIO()
mfile.write(txt)
mfile.seek(0)
a = np.loadtxt(mfile)
print(a)
```

### Edit3 (clipboard input & output)

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
import pyperclip

txt = pyperclip.paste()
mfile = StringIO()
mfile.write(txt)
mfile.seek(0)
a = np.loadtxt(mfile)
pyperclip.copy(a.__str__())
```

Comment: Thank you very much but since I use colab, is there any way to just use data like that not in txt file but just in that form? I mean I just copied and pasted my data into colab

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    array = np.array([i.split() for i in lines], dtype="float")
print(array)
```

Output:

```
array([[44.5, 70.5,  1. ],
       [44. , 66. ,  1. ],
       [33. , 76.5,  1. ]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much but since I use colab, is there any way to just use data like that not in txt file but just in that form? I mean I just copied and pasted my data into colab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn a string into a Numpy array, you can use [`np.fromstring`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html).

```py
import numpy as np

string = "44.5000 70.5000 1.0000 44.0000 66.0000 1.0000 33.0000 76.5000 1.0000"
a = np.fromstring(string, sep=" ")
```

This gives the following output.

```py
>>> a
array([44.5, 70.5,  1. , 44. , 66. ,  1. , 33. , 76.5,  1. ])
```

Then, you can use [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to reshape your Numpy array into a 2D array with 3 columns.

```py
>>> np.reshape(a, (-1, 3))
array([[44.5, 70.5,  1. ],
       [44. , 66. ,  1. ],
       [33. , 76.5,  1. ]])
```

Comment: Thanks but I need 2-d array is there any way I can make it?

Comment: @Mark I have updated my answer.